# Order of Elements in Quotient Groups 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Problem: If $(G:H) = p$, where $p$ is a prime, then the order of every element $a$ not in $H$ ( but $a$ in $G$) is a multiple of $p$.

What I have from previous problem is order of element $Ha$ in $G/H$ is a divisor of the order of $a$ in $G$ (for each $a$ in $G$).

Approach: Order of $Ha$ is $m$ and Order of $a$ is $n$ $\rightarrow$ $n = k m$ ($k$ is an integer) *from previous problem*

Index of $(G:H)$ is $p$, that mean order of $G/H$ is $p$. So we will have $p = hm$ ($h$ is an integer) *order of a group is multiple of order of element inside the group*

So I'm stuck here. Especially I'm not sure how to connect what I got with element a that not in H. Can anyone give me some hints here?

Comment: So $\;H\;$ is any subgroup in $\;G\;$ and its index there is a prime $\;p\;$ . We have to prove then that the order of any element $\;a\in G\setminus H\;$ is a multiple of $\;p\;$ ? This is false, and a lot: for example, take $\;G=S_3\;,\;\;H=\{(1),\,(12)\}\;$ , then $\;[G:H]=2\;$ , yet the order of $\;(123)\in S_3\setminus H\;$ is three. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I think he meant to add the assumption that the subgroup $H$ is normal.  The title indicates there will be a quotient group involved, and he clearly refers to $G/H$ as a group in the observation from the previous problem.

Comment: Perhaps we are assuming that $H$ is normal? Anyways, we have $p=hm$ and $p$ is prime, what does that tell you about $m$?

Comment: @BarrySmith Thank you. Yes, it seem logical to deduce the subgroup is normal

Answer (score 0):

You say "What I have from previous problem is order of element $Ha$ in $G/H$ is a divisor of the order of $a$ in $G$ (for each $a$ in $G$)". That's a great starting point, and a good conjecture to make when thinking about it in the context of this problem is:

Conjecture: the the order of $Ha$ in $G/H$ is $p$.

If you can prove this conjecture, you're done -- you'll know $p$ is a divisor of the order of $a$ in $G$ by the previous problem. The conjecture is a consequence of the following idea, which lets you momentarily avoid thinking about cosets:

Idea:  if a group $\tilde{G}$ has prime order $p$, then any $\tilde{a} \in \tilde{G}$ not equal to the identity has order $p$ in $\tilde{G}$.

So prove this idea, then see how it implies the conjecture, and then you'll be done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\;H\lhd G\;$, we have that

$$|G/H|=p\implies \;\forall\,a\in G\setminus H\;,\;\;ord(aH)=p\implies (aH)^p=a^pH=H\implies$$

$$\implies a^p\in H\implies (a^p)^{ord(H)}=1\implies ord(a)=\text{ multiple of}\;\;p$$

I'm assuming the order of $\;H\;$ is finite.

Comment: How will the last step be clear to Kun?  The most immediately conclusion is only that the order of $a$ is a divisor of $p \,  \mathrm{ord}(H)$, but with no further deduction it could still be coprime with $p$.

Comment: @BarrySmith Thank you. I think it must be clear the order of $\;aH\;$ in the quotient is $\;p\;$, since $\;a\notin H\;$, and since this order is a divisor of the order of $\;a\;$ we should be done. I don't really know what Kun can or can't deduce, I can only assume some other basic things are known to him.

Comment: hi, can you explain a bit more why $a^pH = H$ ? I pretty much understand other parts

Comment: The group $\;G/H\;$ has order $\;p\;$ and then every element in it to the $\;p-$ th power is the unit. That means $\;(aH)^p=a^pH=H=$ the unity in the group $\;G/H\;$ .

Comment: oh yes , I get it now thank you